# Is it possible to enable HTTP2 with apache on FreeBSD

Tags: apache-http-server, freebsd, http-2

I was looking into making my Apache 2.4.46 web server prefer HTTP2 but was unable to find any info on how to enable it with FreeBSD. At this point I'm curious if it's even possible at this time.
Note: I am running HTTPS with lets encrypt certification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, it's easy. Just edit `/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf` and change the line

```
#LoadModule http2_module libexec/apache24/mod_http2.so
```

to

```
LoadModule http2_module libexec/apache24/mod_http2.so
```

Then enable http/2:

```
echo Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1 > /usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes/http2.conf
```

and restart apache:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache24 restart
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and sadly nothing changed. I also added `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1` to my  virtualhost configuration file too... nothing

Comment: Please check if the statement `Include etc/apache24/Includes/*.conf` exists in `/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf`. If not, you should put the line `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1` in `httpd.conf` or add the above `Include...` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot stress this enough! look at your Error logs! I found out that I was having the same issue as as  [The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720116/http-2-configuration-not-running-after-mod-http2-enabled-and-protocols-set-in-co) and that was my underlying problem